# Overlay in sidebar but only for one section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

right now I am having a problem. I have created a calculater by myself. Check it out here: https://radlvoo.de/typ/mtb-fully/ (Last element in the sidebar).

If you select some values and click on the button, the overlay shows up but wrong.. the overlay is going over all the sidebar content. But I just want to have to overlay over the last element, the calculator. How can I do this?

This is my form code so far:

```
<form class="filterform" id="sidebarRahmenhoehenrechner">
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">FAHRRADTYP</label>
<select id="fahrradtypHöhenrechner" class="form-control" name="typ">
<option value="">Bitte wählen…</option>
<option value="trekkingrad">TREKKINGRAD</option>
<option value="cityrad">CITYRAD</option>
<option value="mountainbike hardtail">MOUNTAINBIKE HARDTAIL</option>
<option value="mointainbike fully">MOUNTAINBIKE FULLY</option>
<option value="crossrad">CROSSRAD</option>
<option value="rennrad">RENNRAD</option>
</select>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">GESCHLECHT</label>
<select id="geschlechtHöhenrechner" class="form-control" name="geschlecht">
<option value="">Bitte wählen…</option>
<option value="damen">DAMEN</option>
<option value="herren">HERREN</option>
</select>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">FAHRSTYLE</label>
<input name="fahrstyle" type="radio" value="sportlich" /> Sportlich orientiert
<input name="fahrstyle" type="radio" value="touren" /> Touren orientiert
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">SCHRITTHÖHE</label>
<input id="schritthöheInput" min="0" name="schritthöhe" type="number" />
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-block" style="margin-top: 20px;"><button id="rahmenhöhenRechnerButton" onclick="rahmenhöhenRechnerMain();" type="button">Rahmenhöhe berechnen</button></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="rahmenhöhenRechnerOverlay" style="position: absolute; display: none; z-index: 500; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75); overflow: auto;"><div onclick="disableOverlay();" id="closeButtonOverlay">✖</div><div><p id="rahmenhöheAnzeigen"></p></div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is the overlay code doing:

```
function disableOverlay(){
document.getElementById("rahmenhöhenRechnerOverlay").style.display = "none";
}

function enableOverlay(){
document.getElementById("rahmenhöhenRechnerOverlay").style.display = "block";
}
```

Kind regards

Comment: SOLVED IT MYSELF!

Comment: You could always post the answer to how you fixed it yourself as a community answer!